# Apache Ignite 2.8.0: Node Metrics System View doesn't exist

Tags: java, ignite

According to [documentation](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/system-views) ignite should expose the Node Metrics System View. However there is no such view in the code (`org.apache.ignite.spi.systemview.view` package). Is it a peace of not-implemented-yet feature or is it a bug in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I can see
`org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.sys.view.SqlSystemViewNodeMetrics` in 2.8. It's an internal class so you don't need to use it directly.

Anyway, this is how existing Exporters do this:

```
/**
 * This SPI implementation exports system views as JMX beans.
 */
public class JmxSystemViewExporterSpi extends IgniteSpiAdapter implements SystemViewExporterSpi {
    /** System view registry. */
    private ReadOnlySystemViewRegistry sysViewReg;
    ...

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override public void spiStart(@Nullable String igniteInstanceName) throws IgniteSpiException {
        sysViewReg.forEach(this::register); // I expect NODE_METRICS to be here

        sysViewReg.addSystemViewCreationListener(this::register);
    }
```

Have you tried doing the same?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I know how to obtain the metrics using the MetricExporterSpi. It exports the required information, however it is an old API. The new SystemViewExporterSpi should allow its implementors to get access to the org.apache.ignite.spi.systemview.view.SysView (Node Metrics), however there is no such sys view. And the sql view is a completely different thing :)

Comment: There's `SqlSystemView`. Documentation does not say that you will get a `SystemView`. Instead it lists a number of columns in https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/node_metrics - all available via SqlSystemView/JDBC.

Comment: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/system-views - actually it looks like it does and the same idea was stated in their release video presentation. Again, they do export most of the listed views as SysView entities though the ReadOnlySystemViewRegistry, but for some reason not all of them. It is confusing and my understanding is that it is either a bug in the documentation (it is not explicit enough) or it is a bug in implementation (not implemented yet).

Comment: "A new system view subsystem was introduced. The main goal of the new subsystem is to provide the user with the ability to view lists of Ignite internal entities via several independent pluggable exporters." - so I am writing my own pluggable exporter :)

Comment: I think this is too deep for Stack Overflow, have you considered writing to developers mailing list?

Comment: Nope, haven't written yet. I thought it is possible to clarify the problem here. A comment to your edited answer: actually I was expecting to see the node metrics there as well, but there is no node metrics there. Unfortunately.